# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

We recently upgraded from Sonarqube 5.6 to 6.7.1 and can no longer scan our projects successfully.

Versions I am currently using:

1. SonarQube 6.7.1
2. Java 1.8
3. mysql 5.7

I am executing using mvn sonar:sonar

Error message I am receiving:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project g3: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.4.0.905/sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.10.0.1189/sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project g3: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.4.0.905/sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.10.0.1189/sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.4.0.905/sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.10.0.1189/sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.4.0.905/sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.10.0.1189/sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/jovett/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:142)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.PMDASMClassLoader.loadClass(PMDASMClassLoader.java:65)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.populateType(ClassTypeResolver.java:664)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit(ClassTypeResolver.java:179)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTImportDeclaration.jjtAccept(ASTImportDeclaration.java:62)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:136)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit(ClassTypeResolver.java:170)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTCompilationUnit.jjtAccept(ASTCompilationUnit.java:42)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.TypeResolutionFacade.initializeWith(TypeResolutionFacade.java:17)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.AbstractJavaHandler$5.start(AbstractJavaHandler.java:88)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.usesTypeResolution(SourceCodeProcessor.java:127)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource(SourceCodeProcessor.java:142)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:76)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdTemplate.process(PmdTemplate.java:82)
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executeRules(PmdExecutor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executePmd(PmdExecutor.java:90)
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.execute(PmdExecutor.java:75)
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor.analyse(PmdSensor.java:67)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:283)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:281)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:281)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:281)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:281)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:63)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

I've tried switching the sonar-runner plugin from 3.0.1 to 3.3 to 3.4.0.905 but regardless I am still coming across this exception.

Thanks

Comment: The error comes from PMD. This plugin does not seem to be compatible for a while. I suggest to simply uninstall it and to verify the compatibility of other installed plugins.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I am testing now. I am thrown off because the compatibility matrix suggests that it still should be compatible though: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix.

Comment: My bad, the PMD plugin is still supported and version 2.6 works well on my box. Maybe you should upgrade it, if not already done, and contact the plugin maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the issue and didn't find any solution at the time, however, adding the below dependency under sonar-maven-plugin resolved the issue for me.

Although, my sonar-maven-plugin was `3.6.0.1398`, but the below solution should work.

Hence, the complete plugin would look like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-cipher</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```